# Ошибка: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Я сделал скрипт по парсингу картинок с сайта, у меня в рабочей папке создана папка "Картинки", хочу чтобы туда выгружались картинки, но вылезает ошибка

`File "123.py", line 43, in safe_image
    with open(path, 'bw') as file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\musix\\Desktop\\Работа\\ПТК\\Картинки'`

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

URL = 'https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-poluavtomaticheskoy-svarki-mig'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}
FILE = 'svarka.csv'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_image(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-grid__item js-product-item')
    image = []
    for item in items:
        image.append(
            item.find('img', class_='lozad').get('data-src')
            )
    return  image

def get_folder(img):
    folder = 'Картинки'
    path = os.path.abspath(folder)
    return path

def safe_image(path, img):
    with open(path, 'bw') as file:
        for chunk in img.item_content(8192):
            file.write(chunk)

def parse():
    URL = input('Введите URL: ')
    URL = URL.strip()
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        img = get_image(html.content)
        path = get_folder(img)
        safe_image(path, img)
        print(img)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import uuid

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL = 'https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-poluavtomaticheskoy-svarki-mig'
HEADERS = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*'}
FILE = 'svarka.csv'


def get_image(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-grid__item js-product-item')
    image = []
    for item in items:
        image.append(
            item.find('img', class_='lozad').get('data-src')
        )
    return image


def parse():
    URL = input('Введите URL: ')
    html = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        img = get_image(html.content)
        for i in img:
            with open('Картинки/' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.jpg', 'wb') as file:
                for chunk in requests.get(i):
                    file.write(chunk)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```